# Native Android app crashes with SIGILL on x86

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, x86, android-x86

I'm trying to launch a native Android app on Intel Atom Z2560, but it always crashes in the same place with SIGILL ILL_ILLOPN (illegal operand) signal.

The crash doesn't happen with -O0.

The compiler I'm using is GCC 4.8 from NDK r10. I tried to set -march to atom, but that doesn't change anything.

Anybody knows how can I configure my build scripts so there is no incompatible code generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in NDK r10, see http://b.android.com/73843 for details on it. To avoid the issue, either use an older NDK version, or add (something like) this to your Android.mk:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), x86)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -m32 # NDK r10 x86 bug workaround - http://b.android.com/73843
endif
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Quite weird that they made -m64 the default.

Comment: Actually, `-m64` wasn't set by default, but if neither `-m32` nor `-m64` were specified, it behaved as if `-msse4.2 -mpopcnt` had been specified.

Comment: this workaround isn't needed anymore with the latest NDK r10b release.